# $\Delta ABC$ is right angled triangle. $AP$ and $AQ$ meet $BC$ and $BC$ produced in $P$ and $Q$ and are equally inclined to $AB$.

Tags: triangles

$\Delta ABC$ is right angled triangle at $A$. $AP$ and $AQ$ meet $BC$ and $BC$ produced respectively in $P$ and $Q$ and are equally inclined to $AB$ ($\angle BAP=\angle BAQ$). Show that $\frac{BP}{BQ}=\frac{CP}{CQ}$.

> I used angle bisector theorem and found that $\frac{BP}{BQ}=\frac{AP}{AQ}$. But I don't know how to proceed further. Can this be solved without trigonometry? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Construct **$QQ'$** with **$Q'$** on **$AC$** extended such that **$QQ'=QA$**

> From angle bisector theorem,
> $$\frac{BP}{BQ}=\frac{AP}{AQ}$$
> In $\Delta CPA$ and $\Delta CQQ'$
> $$\angle BAP=\angle BAQ \Rightarrow 90-\angle BAP=90-\angle BAQ \Rightarrow \angle PAC=\angle QAQ'=\angle QQ'C$$
> $$\angle C = \angle C$$
> Therefore,
> $$\Delta CPA \sim \Delta CQQ'$$
> Hence, by similarity,
> $$\frac{BP}{BQ}=\frac{AP}{AQ}=\frac{AP}{QQ'}=\frac{CP}{CQ}$$
> Therefore, the proof is done without trigonomery.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Finish off with the Sine Law.

> From angle bisector theorem, $$\frac {CP}{CQ} = \frac {AP}{AQ}$$ The notations are different since I extended $BC$ towards $C$.
>  By Sine Law, $$\frac {AP}{\sin B} = \frac{BP}{\sin \angle PAB} = \frac {BP}{\sin (90^\circ - \angle PAC)}$$ $$\frac {AQ}{\sin B} = \frac{BQ}{\sin \angle QAB} = \frac {BQ}{\sin (90^\circ + \angle QAC)} = \frac {BQ}{\sin (90^\circ - \angle PAC)}$$
>  Hence $$\frac {AQ}{BQ} = \frac {AP}{BP}$$$$\leadsto\frac {AP}{AQ} = \frac {BP}{BQ} = \frac {CP}{CQ}$$

Comment: In line 5, at the very end, in my opinion, the denominator will be $\sin(90^\circ+\angle PAC)$

Comment: Also, is there any other solution without trigonometry?

Comment: One of the steps was hidden in line 5.